# Android SDK path and error message

Tags: android, eclipse

```
    [2014-01-11 11:30:26 - Android SDK] Warning when loading the SDK:

Warning: Ignoring platform 'adb.exe', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'AdbWinApi.dll', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'AdbWinUsbApi.dll', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'api': build.prop is missing.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'fastboot.exe', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'NOTICE.txt', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'source.properties', not a folder.
Warning: Ignoring platform 'systrace': build.prop is missing.
```

I get this when running eclipse. I check my ..\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools folder and all these files are present. I also check my preferences and direct the path to the SDK location on my pc. But I don't know what going on please help thanks

Comment: check your enviroment variables in Control Panel\System and Security\System you must have the ANDROID_SDK and JAVA_HOME variables set with the right folder address.

Comment: Hmm I don't see it  in 'System' where do I set these variables

Comment: Control Panel\System and Security\System\System Advanced Settings or just go right click on Computer\Properties\Advanced System Settings\Enviroment Variables

Comment: I see it but when I add the variable names as mentioned above what is the correct path ie android sdk -referring to the sdk folder  and JAVA_Home referring to what in the java directory, thanks?

Comment: yes the right path is the root of the sdk, for example my path for ANDROID_SDK_HOME is : `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk` and the path for JAVA_HOME is where the jdk is : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`

Comment: hmm this is not working for me I did it and not change I still have the same error as above and I am not able to access the sdk manager. thanks for your help thus far...but I am now sure what goin on here btw=WIndows 7 64 bit,jdk 1.6

Comment: You can't access to the sdk manager even from the windows explorer?

Comment: Nope, the cmd screen appears for second and then disappears and no sign of response

Comment: Maybe you should download everything again.And don't forget to go to Eclispe/help/Install New Software/Android Development Tools/Developer Tools and NDK plugins. And then try again to open the sdk

Comment: yea maybe, but I downloaded from the android developer website.I tried this already but maybe i did something wrong :( But I will still do dit again form scratch

Comment: See  image -http://i.imgur.com/BDmCkp7.png after reinstalling I get this annoying error when I try get 'Devices' View on eclipse

Comment: I think I figured it out. From other readings I seems to be  a conflict between Comodo Antivirus and the Android SDK so I uninstalled it and Now everything seems to work fine..Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Sorry couldn't help much.